# Npgsql BeginTextImport

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, visual-studio, npgsql

I'm making a program that could connect to my database in PosgresSQL in a VisualBasicScript with Visual Studio. I want to be able to import .csv files just like I can do it on the PSQL SHELL CONSOLE, but for some reason I can't. I've been looking in all kind of websites and documentations, but there's not a specific way of how to use `BeginTextImport` on the internet. All the examples are in C#. And the documentation is too implicit, I could understand what are really the parameters. This is what I have on my code:

```vb
Dim cnn As String
cnn = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Userid=postgres;Database=basedatos;password=123456"
Dim pgCn As NpgsqlConnection = New NpgsqlConnection(cnn)   
pgCn.Open()
pgCn.BeginTextImport("\copy datos.muestreo from 'C:\Users\crist\Desktop\ARCHIVOS FASA\INSERTS\inventarios.csv'" & vbCrLf & "with delimiter ',' CSV header quote E'\''")
```

But when I run it I get this:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Must contain a COPY FROM STDIN command!
>   Parameter Name: copyFromCommand

Comment: `BeginTextImport` is for writing data in yourself, not copying from a file. Also there is no SQL command \copy, that's for psql. Check the documentation how to use those, but I assume you just want to run the copy from a file as a regular command as it is.

Comment: The code you posted obviously isn't VBScript. Is this VB.net? VBA?

Comment: Is vb.net, im using it on form on visual studio, the command  SQL command is Copy, but the server command is \copy, im trying make an import from my csv file from my application by a npgsql connection, but is not working, more precisely i dont undarstand well how the function to import works, i dont know if i need other functions too. The documentation doesnt explain it clearly, and the exxamples are only on C#

Answer (score 2):

As @sami-kuhmonen comments above, `\copy` is a psql command which cannot be used in Npgsql (or any other database driver).

[As the PostgreSQL documentation says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html), if you want to import data from a file *that's available on your PostgreSQL server*, you can use the `COPY table_name FROM filename` as you're trying - but execute that simply with `ExecuteNonQuery`.

`BeginTextImport()` is reserved for when you want to copy data *from the client machine*, i.e. where Npgsql is running. In that case you must use `COPY table_name FROM STDIN`. Consult [the Npgsql documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I already figure it out, i didnt know how to put the input values on the code, but i found the solution with `using writer for file` and `write for each line in file`